# Set a timeout for a specific function / block of code (not the whole script)?

Tags: php, function, timeout

I have php scripts that call perl scripts to do various things and sometimes I get it where it just goes on and on without getting a response back, this is based on the variable that is being passed to the perl script and I am doing a lot of different ones in succession so I can't get really debug it directly since I don't have a response from perl...

I would really like to just be able to set a php function or block of code to timeout after a certain number of seconds.. I have been searching on this but haven't found anything yet on how to do this,

I was thinking something like this could work but I don't think it would dynamically update the $time variable, but maybe there is a way to get this to work? Any advice is appreciated

```
$time = time();
$timeout = $time + 5; //just as an example

do {

// do stuff
} while ($time < $timeout)
```

Comment: you $time inside the while for it to update but if your call of the perl code is inside the while it won't work if that is a call that awaits for the reply of it.

Comment: yeah thats the problem then, it I guess it waits for the return of the perl no matter what

Comment: if you dont really care about the return you could do it different, make the command like: `exec("my_command_here > /dev/null 2>&1 &");` which will execute your code on the background send the output to a black hole. this way your php code will keep running but you will then need a different approch to know weather it has finished or not... you could for example make your perl file create a file with 1 or 0 on it like a PID file and you could control it from your loop like you wanted.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Your best bet would be to use proc_open, sleep for your timeout amount and then call proc_terminate if the process still hasn't completed.

See https://www.php.net/manual/en/book.exec.php for details on the proc_* family.

Comment: I will look into that, I do, however, need a return back from perl, just that in the case of it not giving the return within a reasonable amount of time, I don't have a return to debug it.. I had heard of proc_open before but wasn't sure if I could get a return from it

Answer (score 0):

Well, I'm not so sure this question would have an answer based on how I asked it, so what I am going to do is do the perl call where php doesn't wait for a response and have perl write the output to a text file, then have php read this after specified number of seconds, I think this is the simplest way to do this, its just for a small app i am running on a local server