# setting timeout for php function

Tags: php, timeout, settimeout

i'm developping in php for the first time and i need to know how to add a time out on a specific function:

```
function DoSmthg($resp) {
    .
    .   
    .                              
        $this->GetResponse($resp);
    .
    .
    . 
        return ($resp);
    }
```

I want to add a timeout over thr "GetResponse", so that if the answer takes more than 60 seconds, the function returns "error or 1 or whatever" 
thank you for your help

Comment: And what have you tried? What do you mean with _if the answer takes more than 60 seconds_?

Comment: Use this question for your reference,might be a same question::http://stackoverflow.com/questions/3420328/set-a-timeout-for-a-specific-function-block-of-code-not-the-whole-script

Comment: the GetResponse is trying to retrieve a response from a remote server, so that i don't want to let this function takes more than 1 minute.

Comment: It depends on what exactly `GetResponse` implementation is. There's no way to set execution timeout on PHP function, except external execution: http://us3.php.net/manual/en/book.exec.php

Answer (score 0):

> the GetResponse is trying to retrieve a response from a remote server, so that i don't want to let this function takes more than 1 minute

If you are using cURL to retrieve that, you can use `CURLOPT_TIMEOUT`

```
curl_setopt($ch,CURLOPT_TIMEOUT,60);  // 60 seconds
```